# How to set up applications requiring legacy java on El Capitan (OS X 10.11)?

Tags: java, macos, phpstorm, osx-elcapitan

I have a clean install of El Capitan. I have PHPStorm installed on my Macbook Air. When I try to run the application, I get an error that says PHP storm can't be opened because it requires legacy Java SE 6. I've attached an image of the error below.

[image]

I had the same problem when I installed Yosemite but I was able to install the legacy java fix (Java for OS X 2014-001) from Apple's website. When I try installing that same java fix I get the following Error:
`Java for OS X can't be installed on this disk. A newer version of this package is already installed`

[image]

Any thoughts and help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/apple-java-6-for-10-11.1890762/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming at all, but about the latest Mac OS. [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) is the appropriate site for these types of questions.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/27854363-IDE-doesn-t-start-after-updating-to-Mac-OS-Yosemite-or-Mavericks?page=2 , especially check last (most recent) comments

Comment: JetBrains provide builds with custom Java 8 JDK bundled with actual app -- use them.

Answer (score 25):

Download Java 6 for El Capitan:

Java for OS X 2015-001 Beta

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1824

Comment: Thanks, this actually worked for me. i was trying to run PHPStorm9.

Comment: This fixed it for me also.

Comment: This version doesn't have Java Web Start!

Answer (score 13):

I've used [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install JDK 1.6.0_65:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
brew cask install java6
```

Comment: This was the easiest way for me.

Answer (score 9):

If you have a problem with Java version on OsX Yosemite or El Capitain, you should download bundled Webstorm (or any other IDE from Jetbrains). **It's working, I've tried it by myself.**

https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/

[image]

And yes, this is not a programming related question, but it's an IDE for programming and when you come to work at morning and you can't code — that's problem — and you don't care if it's related ;)

Comment: is it just me or this version that includes a jdk activates the gpu?

Answer (score 0):

i changed version to 1.8 here in below instructions and PhpStorm is now working for me.
At the moment all our products require Apple JDK 1.6 to be installed in order to run on Mac. JDK 1.7 from Oracle is not officially supported yet and has known problems that stop us from using it by default. Oracle JDK 1.7.0_40 has added support for Retina and works much better than previous versions on Mac. You are welcome to give it a try in case you have any problems with Apple JDK.

To force running under JDK 1.7 edit /Applications/.app/Contents/Info.plist file, change JVMVersion from 1.6* to 1.7* :

JVMVersion
1.7*

Answer (score -1):

1. Open Terminal.app and write `sudo nvram boot-args="rootless=0"` + return
2. Reboot
3. Install Java from https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572?locale=en_US

This will install Java 6, 7 and 8. Enjoy!

Comment: First off, I didn't test this but I am almost positive you do not need to turn off rootless to install that. It is provided by Apple and is thus properly signed. Second off, you should _never_ suggest that someone turn off a key security feature of their operating system without a) a proper explanation of what they are doing and the consequences involved and b) offering a reason that is worth the risk c) rehash the risk so they know absolutely positively that they are sure they want to take the risk when they do it. TL;DR: NEVER suggest someone turn off security without a VERY good reason.